# Nested SELECT statement in FROM clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get data from table which name is keeping in another table. Trying to get this as described below leads to getting result from **nested SELECT only**

`select * from (select value from ex_scheme.ex_tab where name = 'ex_name.current_table_name')`

I mean, I've got equivalent result as from just

`select value from ex_scheme.ex_tab where name = 'ex_name.current_table_name'`

query.

UPDATED
Ok, lets double-check if I was correctly understood.
I have to see one table data (lets call this table "table1"). I need to know this table name. And I know where its name is keeping. It is in another table (call it "names_table") in column "name" (row with column value = 'table1'). And I can get it by query 
`select name from names_table where value = 'table1'`

Comment: What is your question?  What is the point of a subquery in this case?  The parent "select" does nothing other than return rows from the subquery

Comment: @OldProgrammer He's trying to implement dynamic SQL, but doesn't know how.

Comment: You may need dynamic sql for that. But you need to understand what to do with the result: if you build a dynamic SQL that gets all the columns from an unknown table, you can not say how much columns you will get, neither their types, so how could you fetch the result?

Comment: @Aleksej In my case I know what columns should be in table, but name of table should be chosen dynamically for some reason. Is this indeed not so typical case?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Point is to take name of table dynamically. But I know what the table in fact is.

Comment: If this is about dynamic SQL then please mention that in the question together with sample data etc. It might be possible to harness the dark power of XML, although that is generally something to avoid unless human life is directly at risk.

Answer (score 0):

try giving alias

```
select n.* from (select value from ex_scheme.ex_tab where name = 'ex_name.current_table_name') n;
```

Update:

> It is in another table (call it "names_table") in column "name" (row
>   with column value = 'table1').

this query will work

```
select n.* from (select name from ex_scheme.ex_tab where name = 'ex_name.current_table_name') n;
```

sub query fetches name of table from another table .

Comment: Thanks, but, unfortunately, result is the same - the result of nested query.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance the column and its type, you can build some dynamic SQL to dynamically query a table or another.

For example, say you have tables like the following:

```
create table table1(col) as (select 1 from dual);
create table table2(col) as (select 2 from dual);
create table tab_of_tabs (tab_name) as (select 'TABLE1' from dual);
```

You can use dynamic SQL to build a query that scans a table whose name is the result of a query:

```
SQL> declare
  2      vSQL    varchar2(1000);
  3      vResult number;
  4  begin
  5      select 'select sum(col) from ' || tab_name -- build the query
  6      into vSQL
  7      from tab_of_tabs;
  8      --
  9      execute immediate vSQL into vResult;       -- run the query
 10      --
 11      dbms_output.put_line('Result: ' || vResult);
 12  end;
 13  /
Result: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could use a nested query in a where clause. For example,

```
select * from table1 where table1.name in (select name from table2);
```

This assumes there's a column "name" in table1. The result of this query should return the rows in table1 that are in table2.